# Cannot handle ConstraintViolationException for Cross-Parameter Constraints/Validations

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have gone through many post related to `ConstraintViolationException` on StackOverflow but couldn't get any help. I am using Spring Boot v2.3.3 web application with spring-boot-starter-validation. I want to validate a password using a custom annotation for Cross-Parameter Constraints. In order to do that, I have followed this [Baeldung link](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints#2-using-cross-parameter-constraints). Below is the implementation class which inherits  `ConstraintValidator`:

```java
@SupportedValidationTarget(PARAMETERS)
public class ValidPasswordValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassword, Object[]> {

    private ValidateRequestTypeEnum requestType;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordValidatorService passwordValidatorService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidPassword constraintAnnotation) {
        this.requestType = constraintAnnotation.requestType();
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object[] value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        SomeUser someUser = (SomeUser) value[0];
        try {
            passwordValidatorService.validate(someUser, this.requestType);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(e.getMessage()).addConstraintViolation();
            return false; // If this is turned true then no exception is thrown
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now whenever I return `false` in the `isValid()` method, I get the `ConstraintViolationException`, even after handling it in the `catch` block. The behaviour remains the same even if I throw a different Exception and handle it in the catch block.

Below are my other class implementaions and stacktrace. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**ValidPassword Annotation:**

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidPasswordValidator.class)
@Target({METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ValidPassword {

    String message() default "";
    ValidateRequestTypeEnum requestType();
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Controller class:**

```java
@Validated
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @ValidPassword(requestType = CREATE_USER)
    @GetMapping("/create-user")
    public void createUser(@RequestBody SomeUser someUser) {
        System.out.println("Create User Mapping");
        System.out.println(someUser.toString());
    }
}
```

**SomeUser Model class:**

```java
public class SomeUser {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

// getters and setters abbreviated
// toString() abbreviated
}
```

**PasswordValidatorService:**

```java
public interface PasswordValidatorService {
    void validate(SomeUser someUser, ValidateRequestTypeEnum requestType) throws ConstraintViolationException;
}
```

**PasswordLengthValidatorImpl:**

```java
@Service
public class PasswordLengthValidatorImpl implements PasswordValidatorService {

    @Override
    public void validate(SomeUser someUser, ValidateRequestTypeEnum requestType) throws ConstraintViolationException {
        switch (requestType) {
            case CREATE_USER:
                System.out.println("From Create_User block");
                if (someUser.getPassword().length() < 8) {
                    throw new ConstraintViolationException("Password length less than 8", new HashSet<>());
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("---Default switch block---");
        }
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```java
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: createUser.<cross-parameter>: Password length less than 8
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:116) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sam.springdroolspersistence.controller.SomeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbaf428.createUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]
```

Comment: I have updated the question correcting the errors. Kindly check once.

Answer (score 2):

> Now whenever I return false in the isValid() method, I get the
> ConstraintViolationException, even after handling it in the catch
> block. The behaviour remains the same even if I throw a different
> Exception and handle it in the catch block.

You can actually try this out in an IDE debugger ( like eclipse) and follow the validation path.
The `isValid` method of `ConstraintValidator` is a contract between validation engine   and your constraint validation logic. If it fails it has to return false.
The actual code that handles it is in `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree`

[image]

The stack trace you are seeing is not what you have thrown and caught - rather it's internally generated in `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for devoting some of your valuable time. The package that contains `ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint ( )` is imported in the project by maven. Could you please mention on how should I handle

Comment: In your example you have handled only password validation. Which other field you want in cross parameter validation.

Comment: I will use the id field and check if the password conatins the id. If it contains then the validation will fail.